# PHP Fatal error with fgets() : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 495545 bytes)

Tags: php

> PHP Fatal error with fgets() : Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes
>   exhausted (tried to allocate 495545 bytes)

I'm getting this error while reading a text file with `fgets()`, but with `fgetc()` it is working fine without any problem. This is the second txt file which i have opened in the same script. After reading the files I have a code of 200 lines which calculate some descriptors. how to eliminate this error?

Comment: How big is this stream that you're reading? (in other words, are you certain you're just running out of memory while reading it?)

Answer (score 0):

Your code has exhausted your allocated memory resources. 
So increase your memory limit like

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '6400M');
```

Adjust the limit according to your needs.

Comment: Think 6400 MB might be a little large?

Comment: You might as well set it to -1 (infinite) then.

Comment: I have put `Adjust the limit according to your needs.` already.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. To itterate over it take about a set amount of lines. Get the pointer position with `ftell`, do something with the data, flush it and continue where you left with `fseek`